# Allocating and returning from function a QSharedPointer on the stack

Tags: c++, qt, smart-pointers, qsharedpointer

Unlike a dumb pointer, I would expect that I could create a `QSharedPointer` on the stack in a function and then return it as return value for assignment to another `QSharedPointer` of the same type, right? Normally, such a pointer would point to memory that is now out of scope and therefore the pointer is not valid, but a `QSharedPointer` will ensure it is retained in memory if another copy of it remains, I would expect. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointer can live on the stack, but the thing to which it points must be on the heap. (Note that the same applies for an ordinary pointer as well as a `QSharedPointer` or a `std::shared_ptr`).

Comment: so if I create it as `QSharedPointer<Interval> newInterval;` and then assign it as `newInterval=QSharedPointer<Interval>(new Interval);` and return `newInterval` then that should satisfy the point you have made, right?

Answer (score 4):

The language you are looking for is: "Returning a QSharedPointer by value" - that is precisely what you're doing. Where you allocate it within a function is an orthogonal issue. You can allocate it on the heap, if you so wish, of course.

The code below won't leak memory and doesn't invoke any undefined behavior. The temporary instance of the shared pointer allocated on the heap in `answer1` will be deallocated by its shared pointer. The pointed-to value in the Q_ASSERT will live until the statement finishes.

```
#include <QSharedPointer>
#include <memory>

QSharedPointer<int> answer1() {
  // shared-pointer-to-integer is on the heap
  std::shared_ptr<QSharedPointer<int>> ptr(new QSharedPointer<int>(new int));
  **ptr = 42;
  return *ptr;
}

QSharedPointer<int> answer2() {
  // shared-pointer-to-integer is a local value
  QSharedPointer<int> ptr = answer1();
  return ptr;
}

int main()
{
   Q_ASSERT(*answer2() == 42);
   return 0;
}
```

There's IIRC nothing in the standard that says that returning anything from a method/function is done using a stack, a register, or anything else in particular. There can be goblins carrying around values carved on slate tablets. As far as C++ is concerned, stack is a class in the std namespace, and there's no other stack to speak about. The language is completely stack-agnostic at the specification level. Stack is an implementation detail that you needn't worry about at this point. You're basically introducing a concept that doesn't belong here.